# Exporting Excel Sheet as CSV with title "Labels YYYY-MM-DD" with a VBA button

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code online, but I believe the original purpose was to export as some other file. Regardless, I want this code to export the excel sheet onto the desktop as a CSV with the name "Labels YYYY-MM_DD". I want this to be able to work regardless of what computer the original Excel sheet is downloaded on.

```
Sub seetest()

Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
user = Environ("Username")
desktop = "C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop\"
today = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")
newfilename = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=desktop & "Labels " & today & ".csv"

End Sub
```

When I click on the button that is assigned this macro, it does export to the desktop but when trying to open the file I receive this error message.[image: Error Message when opening exported CSV]

Any ideas why this is happening/how to fix it? This used to work fine a few days ago, but it's giving me problems yesterday and today.

Edit: I am taking the CSV file and importing it into a PDF editor which automatically fills out all the labels using the CSV that was created. When I do that now, this error message also populates. [image: PDF Editor error]

Edit2: I believe the problem is that the whole workbook is being exported which includes buttons assigned to macros so I believe that is why the error is occurring. How do I change the code so that only range B1:IG2 gets exported as a CSV?

Comment: Add file format `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=desktop & "Labels " & today & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV` . [Other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) are `xlCSVMac, xlCSVMSDOS, xlCSVUTF8`

Comment: Thank you! I just realized the problem is that I have buttons with macros that are being exported with the data for the labels. How would I keep everything the same but rather than exporting the whole workbook, how would I export cells B1:IG2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary workbook, copy range to it, save as csv and close

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub seetest()

    Const CSVDATA = "B1:IG2"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, filename As String
    
    filename = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
               "\Desktop\Labels " & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".csv"
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With Workbooks.Add(1)
        ws.Range(CSVDATA).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .SaveAs filename, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
       
    MsgBox CSVDATA & " exported to " & filename, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: You are incredible. Thank you so so much :D